# Can I write an application to add event to user's google calendar which only me can manage that event?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am writing a web application related to appointment making.

For example, my user is a piano tutor.
He can set his available schedule in my application and someone can reserve a time for his service.  Once this reservation is made, my application will add an event to his google calendar so that he will be able to check his schedule in mobile device.  The problem is, I would like to make this event read only to him.  And if he wants to change/cancel this reservation, he has to login to my application to do so.

My approach is to create a google a/c for my application, create a new calender for every user use my service.  Automatically subscribe this calender to the user's google calendar.  So that he only subscribes my calendar, he can't make any modification to that.

My questions are...
1. Can my application make someone's subscribe the calendar with google api?
2. Can I set that calendar accessable by only him and my application?  So that someone will not able to subscribe even he has the link of the calendar. (this is to protect the privacy of my user)
3. If the above are possible, which api / particular function I will have to use to make it work?  (I am not asking sample code, just want some point to start my studying.  Of coz, sample codes are welcome.)
4. Will there be any limit for calendar I can create in my account?  Since my application may have 1000 or more users, so that I will have to create 1000+ calendar in my google a/c.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your user authenticates using their yahoo or google account then could you not create a special calendar access for that user after authentication. After login you should have all the tools to match.

Comment: But can I make it read only to that user?  It seems not possible as the owner himself should have full control of that calendar.

Comment: Perhaps your clients could be required to obtain your calendar? I don't know. If you are not mixing your doings in the users main calendar then maybe there are other options:(

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I think I am not going to touch his main calendar.  Thats why I have my approach listed in the question.